# Select many return no results

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having problems digging into an xml file using .SelectMany

The xml structure is

```
<data>
  <request>
    <type>LatLon</type>
    <query>Lat 48.85 and Lon 2.35</query>
  </request>
  <current_condition>
    <observation_time>12:38 PM</observation_time>
    <isdaytime>yes</isdaytime>
    <temp_C>16</temp_C>
    <temp_F>61</temp_F>
    <weatherCode>116</weatherCode>
    <weatherIconUrl>
      <![CDATA[
         http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png
      ]]>
    </weatherIconUrl>
    <weatherDesc>
      <![CDATA[ Partly Cloudy ]]>
    </weatherDesc>
    <windspeedMiles>7</windspeedMiles>
    <windspeedKmph>11</windspeedKmph>
    <winddirDegree>20</winddirDegree>
    <winddir16Point>NNE</winddir16Point>
    <precipMM>0.0</precipMM>
    <humidity>51</humidity>
    <visibility>10</visibility>
    <pressure>1018</pressure>
    <cloudcover>75</cloudcover>
    <FeelsLikeC>16</FeelsLikeC>
    <FeelsLikeF>61</FeelsLikeF>
  </current_condition>
  <weather>
    <date>2014-04-11</date>
    <astronomy>
      <sunrise>07:08 AM</sunrise>
      <sunset>08:36 PM</sunset>
      <moonrise>04:45 PM</moonrise>
      <moonset>05:15 AM</moonset>
    </astronomy>
  </weather>
<data>
```

and i'm trying to get the data from astronomy but my results set is empty

My code is:

```
var displayAll = (result.Descendants("data")
                .Descendants("current_condition")
                .SelectMany(astronomy => astronomy.Descendants("weather")
                .Select(wd => new DisplayWeatherCurrentConditions()
                {
                   data removed for clarity as many lines such as 
PrecipMm = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment((string) wd.Element("precipMM")),

                    AstronomyInfo = wd.Elements("astronomy").Select(
                        dwa => new DisplayWeatherAstronomy()
                        {
                            SunRise = (string) wd.Element("sunrise") ?? string.Empty,
                            SunSet = (string) wd.Element("sunset") ?? string.Empty
                        }
                        ).ToList()
                })

                ));


            return displayAll;
```

Any help where I'm going wrong would be appreciated, as I have used many variations but cannot seem to get it right.

Thanks

---------------------------------Code Edit---------------------------

I have managed to get the code to work the way I want, not sure if its the correct way, but this is what I have done.

Created a constructor for class as below:

```
public DisplayWeatherCurrentConditions(DisplayWeatherAstronomy dwa)
        {
            SunRise = dwa.SunRise;
            Sunset = dwa.SunSet;
        }
        public string SunRise { get; set; }
        public string Sunset { get; set; }
```

Then changed code to

```
var displayAll = (from wd in result.Descendants("current_condition")
                   from ts in result.Descendants("astronomy")
```

and finally was able to add properties from astronomy class

```
SunRise = (string)ts.Element("sunrise") ?? string.Empty,
                    Sunset = (string)ts.Element("sunset") ?? string.Empty,
```

If anyone with more experience than me can improve this please do

Comment: invalid xml block it's not complete

Comment: please format your xml to read it better

Comment: `<current_condition>` does not have a descendant `<weather>`.

Comment: where is your ending tag of <data>? is that all of your xml?

Comment: I cut some of the xml as its over 200 lines long

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `SelectMany` does

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `.Descendants("data")` use `result.Descendants("current_condition")` and also I don't see any `weather` element inside of `current_condition`, if you want to get elements that starts with `weather` then you need to use

```
result.Descendants("current_condition")
      .Descendants()
      .Where(x => x.Name.ToString().StartsWith("weather"))
```

Or if you are only interested to get just `weather` elements use `result.Descendants("weather")`

Comment: Hi Selman22 thanks for reply, I have got current conditions returned, but struggling with astronomy as returning 0. Going to keep trying